# Android 11: Can't see contents of "/sdcard/Android/data" even with root

Tags: file-management, android-11

Using rooted file explorers like Solid Explorer, Mix
Mixplorer, I cannot see content of `/sdcard/Android/data`

Why? How to overcome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though it may be trivial, posting the solution to make it easier for those seeking answers

- It's because of restrictions imposed in Android 11. See [Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). Apps are permitted to see *only* their folders and not of those of other apps,with these restrictions.
- If your explorer is updated for Android 11 and you can't see, you can view the content going the long way `root/data/media/0/Android/data`. If your explorer supports, add a favorite tab. Alternatively
  `/sdcard/Android/data`.
- Use a file explorer that is not updated to Android 11 (SDK 30) and you can view directly as before (This is my assumption, haven't tested)

Edit : I just checked [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) app. This app has a file explorer built-in and targets SDK 30. Surprisingly, file explorer of this app can access without any issues. <s>I am guessing that this app has exemptions  given the nature of it's purpose and maybe those exemptions aren't given to file explorers.</s>. From the developer on mail

> I did not make specific changes to the Android/data browsing but SD Maid already had fallback logic that automatically determines what permission levels are required to access a path.

Comment: Ugh! I didn't expect "root apps" would be affected by that "scoped storage" enforcements. But I wouldn't expect devs of such apps updating the targetSDK unaware of that, either. I have no Android-11 device, but maybe you can check via `adb shell` with `su` if root is really (fully) affected?

Comment: @Izzy Developers are aware. It's being discussed in their threads on XDA too. So, it's not a problem of root. They must be having their reasons of updating to latest target SDK. I even left a poor review (later amended), he replied on mail, that this is because of Android 11. So Mr. Root is losing some power :( // One would think it is fair that they updated app description to cover this, without users unpleasantly discovering

Comment: They're updating because Google forces them. There are deadlines. No new apps are accepted if not targeting SDK<new> starting day X, and no updates starting day Z. That said I wonder: root is root – the highest level in the hierarchy. So who would top that? Strange.

Comment: I can't believe it's taken them a decade to implement this. Apps accessing only their own files that they create and manage is the most obvious security enhancement ever.  Second only to assigning permissions to APPS (since apps do things) rather than users. I wish Windows would catch up.  Yay. Flashlight apps will no longer modify my word docs.

Comment: @Triynko also Google Photos can't access other App photos, or file managers work properly

Comment: @beeshyams Why did you mention the path "root/data/media/0/Android/data" ? Is it the same path?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes.....

Comment: @beeshyams I see. So if apps request SAF access to this folder (or one above it), they can overcome the restriction? If so, do you perhaps have the ability to demonstrate it via Github? I've asked about this (here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65967690/878126) , and I also offered a bounty but nobody got an answer .

Comment: @androiddeveloper  Sorry, I don't have understanding to demonstrate. I shared the workaround I found, which was subsequently confirmed by Mixplorer developer in response to my poor rating (revised subsequently) and later saw the same on his XDA thread. You may like to go through the XDA thread or ask the developer to help

Comment: How are file browsers supposed to be able to view `/sdcard` now?

Comment: @Melab without root, they can't browse app private folders

Comment: @Izzy I just tested using `adb shell` on Android 12 (Pixel 3a) and Android 13 (Galaxy M12), and I could browse the files there without root access.