# Missing App Data files after One UI 3.0 update on Samsung

Tags: applications, samsung, files

After updating my Samsung A50s to the version **a507fnxxu5dub6**, which is the One UI 3.0 latest update, I noticed that the app files stored in Android/data are all missing

[image]

Even the obb files are missing from the default file manager, but when I used a third-party file manager, only the obb files are shown

[image]

I already ticked the option to show hidden files to no success, also rebooted the phone, but nothing changed. Tried looking for the patch notes just in case the files had been moved somewhere, but I can't seem to find anything. My apps/games are all working fine so the files are not deleted/removed.

What would be the solution for this? I was planning to share a game including its file, and since the game's folder in the Android/obb does not have its game files, I presumed it must be in the data folder. That's when I noticed the folders are missing

Comment: Likely reason https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231481/131553

Comment: The files are not missing the app you use for folder browsing is not allowed to see them.

Comment: @Robert Is there a way to allow an app the access needed to view the files? I managed to find a file manager that can view it, then copy the file to another destination so that I can share it