# How to view /Android/data directory on external sd card on Android 11?

Tags: root-access, external-sd, storage

After updating to Android 11 I have noticed that I am unable to access the Android/Data/ directory on my external sd card (able to access internal storage /storage/emulated/0/Android/data with Storage Access Framework). This is evidentially due to the new scoped storage requirements.

I believe this an unavoidable fact, if anyone can show otherwise I would be interested to see.

Is it possible to view this directory if the phone has been rooted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 11: Can't see contents of Android /data even with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231481/android-11-cant-see-contents-of-android-data-even-with-root)

Comment: No, unfortunately I am able to view the /Android/data directory on the internal sd card, but not on the external one.

Comment: Update: I rooted the phone, and am able to access the directory on the external SD card. However I would still be interested if this is possible to do without rooting.

Comment: Thanks, here is the relevant part of that page if anyone comes and is curious: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#other-app-specific-dirs.

Comment: Fair enough, upon first glance I just didn't see any information specifically about external sd cards in your link. My fault for not reading closely enough!

Comment: No problem. You can either close it as duplicate yourself or make out an answer expressly clarifying the ext.SD bit

Answer (score 0):

Due to storage changes in Android 11 it is no longer possible to access the  .../Android/Data/ directory on an external sd card on an unrooted phone.

From the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#other-app-specific-dirs):

> On Android 11, apps can no longer access files in any other app's dedicated, app-specific directory within external storage.

It remains possible to access the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ directory, see
[Android 11: Can't see contents of Android /data even with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231481/android-11-cant-see-contents-of-android-data-even-with-root).