# How do I move a data file into an Android emulator application data folder?

Tags: adb, root-access, file-transfer, android-emulator, android-11

I have a favorite Android app that saves its projects as `name.ay` files. I want to import such a file into an AVD running Android 11 so I can work on my PC (Fedora 35), but the app has no import function.

ADB reports that it successfully pushes it to all manner of places, including `/data/mnt/androidwritable/0/emulator/0/Android/data/com.futuresculptor.maestro/files/Maestro/data/`, but the file does not appear anywhere in the emulator. The emulator is rooted and writable as Google API. If I download the .ay file from Gmail, it appears in the Download folder, but when I attempt to move it, the data folder disappears and I'm left only with media and obb folders. The app data is obviously protected but I just want to add one little file. I can do this on my real phone successfully, but not on the emulator.

How can I get the .ay file into the emulator?

Comment: Have you tried to use `adb push ...` from the host PC?

Comment: Possibly related: [Android 11: Can't see contents of Android /data even with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231481/44325)

Comment: Yes, I've pushed it to no avail. I did succeed with Genymotion, so I may have to be content with that.