# Obb folder empty even though I can see inside data folder

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, windows

I looked through everything I could find but I couldn't find a specific answer to this, sorry. I'm using a Samsung phone running android 13 - it isn't rooted and I can't risk rooting it. Both by using a computer through USB and through the AOSP Files app, I can see files inside the android/data folder, but inside the android/obb folder is appearing to be empty.

This seems strange, firstly as: I read that obb folders are only created when an app needs them, so I'm not sure why it would create them and then leave it empty. And secondly, because I would think there are other files inside these apps that are not showing up within the data folders, as some of the apps are quite big and there aren't files corresponding to certain things that seem to happen too quickly to be downloaded as they're needed - as well as, with how spotty the internet I use is, I would expect to have seen more connection errors as the game tried to access them if they *were* being downloaded each time.

Do I just not have the right permission to look in the obb folder, even though I can see in the data folder? And if so, is there a way to look inside it without root? For reference, I use a Windows computer. Thanks for any help you can give.

**Edit:** The file manager linked in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/wsnhct/file_manager_dev_discovers_a_new_loophole_to_get/) about accessing the /data and /obb folders in Android 13 can apparently allow the user to access folders through launching the file manager as if it was within the app the folders belong to. However, even through this, the /obb folder appears to be empty on my phone.

The /obb folder is also empty in the com.sec.android.app.samsungapps app - could anyone with root access who also has that app look inside the /obb folder and confirm whether it is indeed simply empty, or whether I still cannot access it?

If it is truly empty, is there anywhere else that the data from a large app (.eg saved games, animations, character images - all things which I would think would be within the app itself due to fast loading speeds and the lack of connection errors, but are not appearing within the /data folder) might be stored that I am unable to find?

**Edit 2:** I've been looking into various `ADB` and `ADB shell` commands following [this list of commands on Github](https://gist.github.com/Pulimet/5013acf2cd5b28e55036c82c91bd56d8). Is the `adb shell pm grant <package name> <permission>` only for things like giving permission to apps to use the camera? Or is there a way (not necessarily with this command) to use ADB to change things like read/copy permission? I have seen posts up until fairly recently say that you can still access `data` and `obb` through a PC, but they often don't mention how.

Comment: It's a bit strange that you can see files inside `/android/data` without being rooted since I couldn't see any files inside `/android/data` on Samsung Galaxy M12, Android 13. Are you by any chance using an external SD card?

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought it was strange as well - I'm not using an external SD card and can't see an SD card folder on it (this phone is refurbished, so I don't know if it's ever had one in it.) Following this Reddit post (https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/yqenbr/how_to_access_android_13_data_and_obb_folder/) I downloaded the app which provides a shortcut into AOSP file manager. I don't know for the main app I'm interested in, but the app com.sec.android.app.samsungapps also appears to have an empty obb folder, and I can't think of a good reason for it other than permissions.

Comment: I just checked on my Pixel 3a running Android 12 and I can see the content of `/obb` but not `/data` using [Files by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) app. However, I am still unable to access `/obb` on Galaxy M12 running Android 13 even though I know for sure that there are files inside there, since it stated "modified x minutes ago" just after I installed a big game.

Comment: This might be related: [Android 11: Can't see contents of "/sdcard/Android/data" even with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231481/44325), though I could browse `/obb` and `/data` using `adb shell`, if that's possible for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering this again! I'm a beginner with adb, but I gave it a shot. In `adb shell`, when I used `$ cd /sdcard/android/obb/<app name>` and used `$ ls`, it didn't return anything, as if it's still empty. Is this the correct obb folder? Or maybe the wrong commands?