# Where are the locations where games store data?

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I am trying to find the sprites for a game. They were not in the apk. I looked in /sdcard/Android/obb. But while there was a folder that matched the game, it was empty. I looked in /sdcard/Android/data but could not find any files that had images in them. I looked in /data/data/ and the same thing happened. My understanding is that the files have to be stored somewhere on the phone, right?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. The game data might be stored there, although file manager apps may not be able to list the content due to the Android restriction. Possibly related: [Obb folder empty even though I can see inside data folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250473/44325), [Android 11: Can't see contents of "/sdcard/Android/data" even with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231481/44325), and the canonical [Where do Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/44325).

Comment: Note that games usually don't contain separate images, often they combine them in a few bigger file. The file structure of such files can be proprietary so searching for image files won't be successful even if you had permission to access all the mentioned paths.

Comment: I can see obb files for a different game in the obb directory, so I don't think restrictions is the reason why. Also, the game is made in Unity so I'll probably be able to extract the assets since there's a bunch of tools for that.

Comment: What game are you talking about? Some games hide their assets in other files. Does the game require wifi to launch or does it work offline? If it works offline, the files are inside the apk and you need to do some digging, try looking in the largest files first, assets are usually pretty large.

Comment: The game is called "Bonbon Cakery". It runs without wifi, but I don't know if that's because the files are stored in the APK or just because it downloaded the assets the first time I opened it, since it took a while to open the first time. I unzipped the apk and put all the files into Asset Ripper (for Unity) and it only showed me the icons and the start screen.